# ReactJS poll database or receive data being pushed from server

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api, redux

I am having a hard time deciding on how to best implement what I thought would be a simple scenario. I need to either have React poll a database or API(which seems like an in-efficient solution) or be able to "push" data from another server into a react application.

Websockets seems to be able to solve this. But to me it seems very complicated to solve something that cannot be that unique of a problem. The backend server will be a ASP.Net WebAPI and I can easily have that polling the database and therefore only dispatch/call when something needs to reach the React app. But I cannot seem to find simple implementations of this in React? Perhaps it is just my search skills that are lacking, so perhaps just pointing me in directions on what to search for would be helpful.

Comment: You can use signalR or rethinkdb

Comment: SignalR looks very promising. I will research a bit more and see if it solves my problem. But thanks a lot for the rapid response!